# How to circumvent the is laggy/buggyness in Eclipse 3.8 WDT Javascript

Tags: javascript, eclipse

For big javascript/node.js projects, Eclipse seems very buggy.

- Ctrl+Space autocomplete with template? **Hang for 30 seconds** and optionally show error in stead of dialog: `Java heap space error`
- Ctrl+H workspace-wide search? Errormessage when complete.
- At random intervals? Error message.

  - `An internal error occurred during: "Requesting JavaScript AST from selection"`
  - `Errors running builder 'JavaScript Validator' java.lang.NullPointerException`
  - Solution: Keep error message open and drag it away from the screen.

I often read solutions about disabling Javascript validation. But that's not really a solution, is it? I want to keep my validation. Occurrences marked. Unread variables marked. Etc.

What are known 'workarounds' to stop this carousel of delays and errors?

Comment: Have you tried the current release, in Kepler SR1?

Comment: Nope. Word on the street is that the `4.x` branch is buggy and slow. It has many performance complaints. The unnamed `3.8` release was specifically released as a faster and more stable alternative to `4.x`.